# Any way to avoid haml code duplication without creating new file?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I have the following code in a .haml template file in a Sinatra app:

```
- if(@order == 'inverse') 
    - @list.reverse_each do |item| 
        .item
            %span.action-move(data-icon="o")
            .detail.title=item[0]
            .detail.content=item[1]
            %span.action-delete(data-icon="d")
- else 
    - @list.each do |item| 
        .item
            %span.action-move(data-icon="o")
            .detail.title=item[0]
            .detail.content=item[1]
            %span.action-delete(data-icon="d")
```

As you can see, 5 lines of code are identical. Is there a way that I can refactor this code to avoid the duplication here *without* creating an additional file to use as a partial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head - you could create a temp list that you would set in the conditionals and then loop through the temp list like so:

```
- if(@order == 'inverse')
  - temp = @list.reverse
- else 
  - temp = @list
- @temp.each do |item| 
  .item
    %span.action-move(data-icon="o")
    .detail.title=item[0]
    .detail.content=item[1]
    %span.action-delete(data-icon="d")
```

Comment: You could also do this with an `Enumerator`, which would avoid creating a new list, e.g. `- temp = ((@order == 'inverse') ? @list.reverse_each : @list.each)` (although I’d use a different name than `temp`).

Comment: I ended up going with the enumerator method, which works quite well and had the added advantage of forcing me to learn how to use Enumerator.new! (This is my first major project done in Ruby)

Answer (score 0):

```haml
- (@order == 'inverse' ? @list.reverse : @list).each do |item| 
  .item
    %span.action-move(data-icon="o")
    .detail.title=item[0]
    .detail.content=item[1]
    %span.action-delete(data-icon="d")
```

Or, as @matt suggests:

```haml
- (@order == 'inverse' ? @list.reverse_each : @list.each).each do |item| 
  .item
    %span.action-move(data-icon="o")
    .detail.title=item[0]
    .detail.content=item[1]
    %span.action-delete(data-icon="d")
```