# How do I avoid markup duplication in haml templates?

Tags: ruby, haml, code-duplication

I saw [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927113/any-way-to-avoid-haml-code-duplication-without-creating-new-file), but I believe there are certain differences here, that is this code can't be fixed that way. Let's consider the following code:

```
- if image['href']
    %a{href: image['href']}
        <some markup>
- else
    <some markup>
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid duplication without moving code to the other file?

**UPD** It appears my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237308/how-can-i-conditionally-wrap-some-haml-content-in-a-tag).

Comment: if you are using rails then set `<some markup>` as a partial and change `<some markup>` for `render :name_of_partial`

Comment: @Aguardientico First, I don't use `rails`, second I was asking about not moving code to the other file.

Comment: then you can use: `- the_markup = "<some markup>"` and change `<some markup>` for `= the_markup`

Comment: @Aguardientico I can't deny this will work, but more readable solution is desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haml 4.1 (currently in [beta](http://rubygems.org/gems/haml/versions/4.1.0.beta.1) – it [might be version 5](https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/761) when it’s released) contains a [`haml_tag_if`](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/4.1.0.beta.1/lib/haml/helpers.rb#L524-565) method that will do what you want:

```haml
- haml_tag_if image['href'], :a, href: image['href'] do
  some markup
```

This will produce either:

```html
<a href='foo'>
  some markup
</a>
```

or just

```html
some markup
```

depending on whether `image['href']` is truthy.

If you don’t want to upgrade yet, you can add the method yourself as a helper, see this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8595810/214790 (the code there is basically the same as the new code in Haml itself).

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to upgrade to haml 4.1 beta?

Comment: @x-yuri `gem install haml --pre` will install the gem. If you’re using Bundler add `gem 'haml', '4.1.0.beta.1'` to your `Gemfile`.